# WP User Query multiple AND OR query problem

Tags: wp-query

My problem is the following I'm trying to return the following.

```
If 
  user_login=$name_input AND 
  referrer=25 AND 
  qualified=0
  return results 

OR if 
  passup=26 AND 
  user_login=$name_input 
  return results.
```

At the moment it returns the results if any of the arrays is true.
It seams that the AND is not working?

```
$name_search =  array(
'search_columns' => array( 'user_login' ),
'search' => '*'.esc_attr( $name_input ).'*',

'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
             'key' => 'user_login',
            'value' => $name_input,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'   
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'referrer',
            'value' => '25',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'qualified',
            'value' => '0',
            'compare' => '='
        ),

    ),
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'passup',
            'value' => '26',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
             'key' => 'user_login',
            'value' => $name_input,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'

        ),


  ),
),
 );
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

This is the SQL:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt3 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt3.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt4 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt4.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (756,1278,1369,1474,1560,1627,1679,1737) AND ( 
  ( 
    ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'user_login' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%bob%' ) 
    AND 
    ( mt1.meta_key = 'referrer' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) = '25' ) 
    AND 
    ( mt2.meta_key = 'qualified' AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS CHAR) = '0' )
  ) 
  OR 
  ( 
    ( mt3.meta_key = 'passup' AND CAST(mt3.meta_value AS CHAR) = '26' ) 
    AND 
    ( mt4.meta_key = 'user_login' AND CAST(mt4.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%bob%' )
  )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'op_preview' OR wp_posts.post_author = 24 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: What's the generated SQL query?

Comment: How do I find the generated SQL query?

Comment: E.g. with `$q = new WP_Query( $args ); echo $q->request;`

Comment: @birgire please see above the SQL

Comment: @brigier passup as well as qualified and referrer are user_meta keys this sql doesn't look right????

Comment: ahh sorry I wrote `WP_Query` instead of `WP_User_Query` here ;-)

Comment: I think I have to use WP_Meta_Query since these values are stored in the user_meta table.

Comment: Using `meta_query` in `WP_User_Query` works on the users meta table via `WP_Meta_Query`.

Comment: The SQL is not right don't you think?

Comment: Why are you using 2 separate arrays in your args, if they are all AND? Have you tried putting the passup and user_login in the first array?

Comment: Because I need two statements with multiple AND statments . if you have a look I had two conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the search part is not working as you expect, because your *search columns* setup:

```
'search_columns' => 'user_login',
```

is within the meta query and therefore not active.

Move it out of the *meta query* part:

```
$user_query = WP_User_Query(
    [
        'search_columns' = [ 'user_login' ],   //<-- array of column names
        ... 
    ]
);
```

Otherwise the search columns will be `user_login`, `user_url`, `user_email`, `user_nicename` and `display_name`.

This is the generated SQL query for your current user query:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT 
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_users.* 
    FROM wp_users 
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON ( wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id ) 
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_users.ID = mt1.user_id ) 
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_users.ID = mt2.user_id ) 
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS mt3 ON ( wp_users.ID = mt3.user_id ) 
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS mt4 ON ( wp_users.ID = mt4.user_id ) 
    WHERE 1=1 
        AND 
        ( 
            ( 
                    ( wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'user_login' 
                      AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%test%' ) 
                AND ( mt1.meta_key = 'referrer' AND mt1.meta_value = '25' ) 
                AND ( mt2.meta_key = 'qualified' AND mt2.meta_value = '0' ) 
            ) 
            OR 
            ( 
                    ( mt3.meta_key = 'passup' AND mt3.meta_value = '26' ) 
                AND ( mt4.meta_key = 'user_login' AND mt4.meta_value LIKE '%test%' ) 
            ) 
        ) 
        AND 
        ( 
                user_login LIKE '%test%' 
            OR user_url LIKE '%test%' 
            OR user_email LIKE '%test%' 
            OR user_nicename LIKE '%test%' 
            OR display_name LIKE '%test%'
        ) 
    ORDER BY user_login ASC
```

where we notice the multiple `OR` in the search part.

Comment: Where do I place it?

Comment: similar to your  'search' input parameter - I updated the answer @Nelson101

Comment: I'm a niewbie how did you get that SQL ? What is the wp_user_query ?

Comment: It's `$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args ); echo $user_query->request; ` where `$args` is your `$name_search` array. @Nelson101

Comment: I will test this in the morning getting late now many thanks in advance @birgire

Comment: ok, good luck with it - Hope you don't have huge number of users, the query might be heavy for large tables ;-)  @Nelson101

Comment: Good point what if I move the user_login key from the wp_users table to the   user meta table would that improve the performance ?

Comment: The best measure is to test it on the install ;-) You could also see what [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) gives @Nelson101

Comment: I don't understand how to put the search columns and still have the args in the WP_User_Query at the same time? @birgire

Comment: just add `'search_columns' = array( 'user_login' ),` into your `$name_search` array, e.g. as the first element  @Nelson101

Comment: I added the following:
`$name_search =  array(
'search_columns' => array( 'user_login' ),
'search' => '*'.esc_attr( $name_input ).'*', ` and it didn't work. @birgire

Comment: It's still searching user_login, user_url, user_email, user_nicename and display_name. @birgire

Comment: That's strange, the sorting columns setup works fine on my vanilla test install, so I'm not sure what I can suggest more other than starting with the most basic query and add to it in small steps.  I'm stopping now since long comment threads are not recommended on this site. Best of luck. @Nelson101